Speed efficient data collection from pydantic model
I'm using python 3.11 and pydantic 2.7. I want to collect specific info from my model, and the actual model is very big one. So how can I collect data when parsing/validating the model quicker?
My code with speed checker:
import copy
from time import perf_counter as time
from typing import Any, ClassVar

from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator


class Employees(BaseModel):
    name: str
    employees_names: ClassVar[list[str]] = []

    @field_validator('name')
    @classmethod
    def collect_employees_names(cls, value):
        cls.employees_names.append(value)

        return value


class EmployeesNative(BaseModel):
    name: str


class Manager(BaseModel):
    name: str
    employees: list[Employees]
    managers_names: ClassVar[list[str]] = []

    @field_validator('name')
    @classmethod
    def collect_managers_names(cls, value):
        cls.managers_names.append(value)

        return value


class ManagerNative(BaseModel):
    name: str
    employees: list[EmployeesNative]


class Results(BaseModel):
    managers: list[Manager]


class ResultsNative(BaseModel):
    managers: list[ManagerNative]


class Data(BaseModel):
    results: list[Results]


class DataNative(BaseModel):
    results: list[ResultsNative]


class Schema(BaseModel):
    data: Data


class SchemaNative(BaseModel):
    data: DataNative


man1 = {'name': 'max', 'employees': [{'name': 'Jorge'}, {'name': 'Sasha'}]}
man2 = {'name': 'kate', 'employees': [{'name': 'Eva'}, {'name': 'Mike'}, {'name': 'Riss'}]}
man3 = {'name': 'bub', 'employees': []}
man4 = {'name': 'slava', 'employees': [{'name': 'Martha'}]}

res1 = {'managers': [man1]}
res2 = {'managers': [man2, man3]}
res3 = {'managers': [man4]}


def parse_native(obj: dict[str, Any]) -> list[str]:
    """ Get all persons names in schema. """
    mod = SchemaNative.model_validate(obj)

    m = [m.name for res in mod.data.results for m in res.managers]
    e = [e.name for res in mod.data.results for m in res.managers for e in m.employees]
    r = m + e
    print('native: ', r)

    return r


def parse_validators(obj: dict[str, Any]) -> list[str]:
    """ Get all persons names in schema. """
    Schema.model_validate(obj)
    r = Manager.managers_names + Employees.employees_names
    Manager.managers_names = []
    Employees.employees_names = []
    print('validators: ', r)

    return r


def run_test(func, objs, comment='', reps=1, average=True, prec=.6):
    """ Speed checker. """
    total = 0
    for _ in range(reps):
        for e in objs:
            beg = time()
            func(e)
            end = time()
            total += (end - beg)
    t = total / reps if average else total
    print(f'{t:{prec}f} ({comment})')


# payload for tests
test_obj = {'data': {'results': [res1, res2, res3]}}
payload = tuple(copy.deepcopy(test_obj) for _ in range(1))

# number of repetitions
REPS = 1

run_test(func=parse_native, objs=payload, comment='No validators', reps=REPS)

run_test(func=parse_validators, objs=payload, comment='With validators', reps=REPS)


I tried to set instance variables in nested models and override .model_validate() method with no luck

Thanks for sharing such detailed code.
The problem is in using type ClassVar for storing employees_names. In this case the class attribute will persist all external updates. Basically it will save all latest updates until you explicitly call to clear them.
For example you can do this inside parse_validators function.
def parse_validators(obj: dict[str, Any]) -> list[str]:
    """ Get all persons names in schema. """
    Schema.model_validate(obj)
    r = Manager.managers_names + Employees.employees_names
    Manager.managers_names = []
    Employees.employees_names = []

    print('validators: ', r)
    return r

Sorry for not giving any better suggestions, but I think this is the best advice I can provide without doing a lot of code refactoring.
One more thing, instead of field_validators consider using def model_post_init(self, __context: Any) I think it was purposely build for updating some variables based on already intialized all other variables.

Thanks for the reply. I will look into model_post_init, ClassVar was used as an example of what i was trying to do

Thx Alexander, also if my answer will solve your issue pls don't forget to mark it as accepted this will mark that your question is cloded. thx

Both variants of using your suggested methods are slower in terms of speed than using list comprehension. So i'm not going to resolve the issue yet. Thx

Maybe you please consider editing the question in the problem - and write a bit more clear the actual problem is not data that persist between runs, but in smth else, smth related to speed of validation?
